# Why is my sprite not displaying correctly in firefox?

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, sprite

I have built a css sprite for the middle navigation bar of my website. In every other browser it displays correctly - all in a neat line. However, in firefox, the final button/link is displayed slightly lower than the rest of the bar and I'm not sure why.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="midnavbar">
<ul id="midnav">
<li id="midnav-1"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/?page_id=13"    title="Community Connections">Community Connections</a></li>
<li id="midnav-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/?page_id=18 " title="Community Living">Community Living</a></li>
<li id="midnav-3"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/?page_id=118" title="Autism Spectrum">Autism Spectrum</a></li>
<li id="midnav-4"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/?page_id=123" title="Positive Support">Positive Support</a></li>
<li id="midnav-5"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/?page_id=121" title="Medically Fragile">Medically Fragile</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#midnavbar {
display:block;
}

ul#midnav {
width:955px;
height:48px;
list-style:none;
overflow:hidden;
}

ul#midnav li {
display:inline;
list-style:none;
}

ul#midnav li a {
height:48px;
float:left;
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}
ul#midnav li#midnav-1 a {
width:223px;
background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-    content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat 0 0; /* X and Y position at 0 */
}
ul#midnav  li#midnav-1 a:hover {
background-position:0 -48px; /* Y position -45px for Over instance image */
}
ul#midnav li#midnav-2 a {
width:178px;
background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-   content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat -223px 0;
}
ul#midnav  li#midnav-2 a:hover {
background-position:-223px -48px;
}
ul#midnav li#midnav-3 a {
width:179px;
background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat -401px 0;
}
ul#midnav  li#midnav-3 a:hover {
background-position:-401px -48px;
}
ul#midnav li#midnav-4 a {
width:186px;
background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat -580px 0;
}
ul#midnav  li#midnav-4 a:hover {
background-position:-580px -48px;
}
ul#midnav li#midnav-5 a {
width:189px;
background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat -766px 0;
}
ul#midnav  li#midnav-5 a:hover {
background-position:-766px -48px;
}
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong so I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Upload the sprite image somewhere

Comment: You have `wp-   content` (note the spaces) in some of the `url()` declarations - hopefully just a copy/paste glitch, but...

Comment: Better than just uploading the sprite image : build a complete [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) based on the uploaded sprite. But a slight positionning error in the image is the first thing coming to mind.

Comment: It was a copy and paste error - the spaces aren't in the original.

Comment: Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcTKW/)

Comment: The URL's are not good on jsfiddle

Comment: Okay, it should work now. I was using the URL for my locally hosted image. I apologize for the mix up.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `display: inline;` because it's buggy, and as you've figured it out it doesn't really work the same in all browsers. I suggest you use `float: left;` Also I cleaned up your css a bit.

```
#midnav {
    width: 955px;
    height: 48px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#midnav li {
    float: left;
}

#midnav a {
    height: 48px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#midnav-1 a {
    width: 223px;
    background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-    content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat 0 0; /* X and Y position at 0 */
}

#midnav-1 a:hover { background-position:0 -48px }

#midnav-2 a {
    width:178px;
    background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-   content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat -223px 0;
}

#midnav-2 a:hover { background-position:-223px -48px }

#midnav-3 a {
    width:179px;
    background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat -401px 0;
}

#midnav-3 a:hover { background-position:-401px -48px }

#midnav-4 a {
    width:186px;
    background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat -580px 0;
}

#midnav-4 a:hover { background-position:-580px -48px }

#midnav-5 a {
    width:189px;
    background: transparent url("http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/thoriumific/images/midnav.jpg") no-repeat -766px 0;
}

#midnav-5 a:hover { background-position:-766px -48px }​
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, it didn't help, in fact it only messed up my layout more. :-/

Comment: What happened?
The problem with floats is, that you have to clear them.
Also it would help to see a working example of your project.

Comment: I figured it out! by making the container larger AND eliminating display:inline it worked!